# How do I stop IE11 from making these two lines go on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have an issue with IE11 only (Chrome + FF works fine) where 2 lines are going "on top" of each other.

Here's the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/3L2bx9w9/2/

HTML:

```
<div>
  <label>first line first line first line first line</label>
  <div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="contentFieldset">
        <div class="inner">
          second line second line second line second line
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <label>first line first line first line first line</label>
  <div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="contentFieldset">
        <div class="inner">
          second line second line second line second line
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.contentFieldset {
  flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

This nested structure is required for my setup (I've obviously simplified it for this example), and it works if the top div has a static height set (for example, 250px) but I need it to fill the available space.

Does anyone know of a workaround that I can use to make it work without removing flexbox or saying not to use IE? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

For whatever reason, it appears the `-ms-flex` line must be set to `1 0 auto;` instead of just `1`. So the corrected CSS would look like:

```
.content {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.contentFieldset {
  flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-width: 0;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure why this works, but I suspect the default for -ms-flex is processed differently then flex in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of other issues with this, change your "display: flex" to "display: block".  Worked for me in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3L2bx9w9/3/

```
.content {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.contentFieldset {
  flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue with changing it to block is that .content no longer fills the height of what it's in, which is why I'm using flex to begin with.

Comment: Then you may need to come up with another way for the content to fill the height of what it's in.  I'm not sure you'll find another way to fix the IE11 bug.

Comment: I did find a way, look above. I had to modify -ms-flex to be 1 0 auto instead of just 1. What a pain.